# How do I put a hyperlink inside a list in Markdown on GitHub Pages?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

I have tried the following syntax to make a Markdown list item on a GitHub page of mine a hyperlink:

```
  1. [Caption]: https://example.com
  2. Another list item
```

Contrary to intuitive expectations it renders into the following HTML code

```
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li>Another list item</li>
</ol>
```

How can this possibly be fixed? Is there a correct syntax for this? My intention was to create a clickable list of sources of the information used to write the article and put it in the bottom part of it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It should be:

```
  1. [Caption](https://example.com)
  2. Another list item
```

Answer (score 4):

From GitHub's "[Mastering Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#Links)":

## Links

```
http://github.com - automatic!
[GitHub](http://github.com)
```

---

[image: Mastering Markdown]]

https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#Links